# Programmatically creating a simple product, showing a blank screen and not added

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, simple-product

Upon running the script I only see a blank screen and nothing is updated within admin. Everything set in this file exists in my installation so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Also if I remove the try/catch block I get a few errors. **Is there any documentation for this?**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)); 

try {
    //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product(); 

    // Build the product 
    $product->setSku('testing product'); 
    $product->setAttributeSetId('9');# 9 is for default 
    $product->setTypeId('simple'); 
    $product->setName('Some cool product name'); 
    $product->setCategoryIds(array(3)); 
    $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, 1 is default 
    $product->setDescription('Full description here'); 
    $product->setShortDescription('Short description here'); 
    $product->setPrice(39.99); # Set some price

    //Default Magento attribute 
    $product->setWeight(4.0000); 

    $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
    $product->setStatus(1); 
    $product->setTaxClassId(0); # default tax class 
    $product->setStockData(array( 
    'is_in_stock' => 1, 
    'qty' => 99999 
    )); 

    $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 
    $product->save();
}   catch (Exception $ex) { 
    # ..
}
```

Comment: add `print_r($ex)` inside the `catch` statement and see what is printed out

Comment: @Marius: I get an error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DE)` any idea?

Comment: You can try setAttributeSetId(9) and what the error says is: "You fail to give me a correct attribute set id" - I think :-) are you sure you have a set with id 9? Because in a default installation the maximum attribute_set_id is 8.

Comment: hello, did you find an answer? i get no exception but no product is adding.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, it looks like you are trying to use an attribute set that does not exist.

Make sure that the attribute set id `9` exists.
If you are 100% sure it exists then try it without the quotes:

```
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);
```

instead of

```
$product->setAttributeSetId('9');
```